# List of checkbox Django ModelForm

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I'm creating a very simple form,
[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22vpp.png)

I would like to have a radio select checkbox (instead of a choice list like I have now)
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eieCQ.png)

I'll have more questions in my form afterward, and i think it'll be easyer for the user with some 'radio select'

I've tried to put some `widget=forms.RadioSelect` in my model but it seems we can't do that here
Do you know how I could do this ?

Here is my code :

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms


class Post(models.Model):
    SAMPLE_CHOICES =( 
    (0, "Very satisfied"), 
    (1, "satisfied"), 
    (2, "neutral"), 
    (3, "not very satisfied"), 
    (4, "not satisfied at all"), 
    )    
    q1 = models.IntegerField(choices = SAMPLE_CHOICES, verbose_name=u"cleanliness of the premises")
    q2 = models.IntegerField(choices = SAMPLE_CHOICES, verbose_name=u"quality of services")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

views.py

```
from .forms import PostForm
from.models import Post
from django.shortcuts import render


def post_new(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid()) # some debug
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(Post.objects.all()[-1].q1) # I print the form i just saved for debug purpuse
    

    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('q1', 'q2')
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Satisfaction form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Satisfaction form</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want change widget for your field in `ModelForm` you can do it in `class Meta:`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('q1', 'q2')
        widgets = {
            'q1': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```